# List not displaying in descending order

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to display a list in descending order. However, the output is taking the sort order of X list and not of top10. I assume the former list gets precedence. Is there any way to sort top10 in descending order?

```
public with Sharing class EngagementDeltaController {

 public Engagement__c[] getDelta() {

 Engagement__c[] x = [SELECT Name,ID,Engagement_Score__c,CreatedDate,Account_ID__c,Delta__c,Account_Name__c,Strategic_Account_Tier__c 
                  FROM Engagement__c 
                  ORDER BY Account_ID__c,CreatedDate ASC];

 Engagement__c[] top10 = [SELECT Name,ID,Engagement_Score__c,CreatedDate,Account_ID__c,Delta__c,Account_Name__c,Strategi   c_Account_Tier__c 
                      FROM Engagement__c       
                      Where ID IN :x AND Delta__c != NULL 
                      ORDER BY Delta__c DESC ]; 


if(!x.isEmpty())
 {
   for(Integer i=1; i<x.size();i++)
{
    if(x[i].Account_ID__c == x[i-1].Account_ID__c)
    {
         x[i].Delta__c = x[i].Engagement_Score__c-x[i-1].Engagement_Score__c;              
         top10.add(x[i]); 

      i++;            
    }     
    else system.debug('nothing found');
}  
}

return top10; 
 }
}
```

Comment: What type of field is delta__c? Is it a number, lookup, etc?

Comment: Delta__c = number field

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend avoiding querying every object in your record set:

```
ngagement__c[] x = [SELECT Name,ID,Engagement_Score__c,CreatedDate,Account_ID__c,Delta__c,
    Account_Name__c,Strategic_Account_Tier__c 
    FROM Engagement__c 
    ORDER BY Account_ID__c,CreatedDate ASC];
```

You should add a where or limit clause to restrict your record set. If you actually want the entire set, switch to using a query locator and pagination techniques instead:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Paginating_Data_for_Force.com_Applications

As for the top 10 List, you should add **LIMIT 10**:

```
Engagement__c[] top10 = [SELECT Name,ID,Engagement_Score__c,CreatedDate,Account_ID__c,
Delta__c,Account_Name__c,Strategi   c_Account_Tier__c 
FROM Engagement__c       
Where ID IN :x AND Delta__c != NULL 
ORDER BY Delta__c DESC LIMIT 10];
```

That being said, by looking at your code, the top10 query may not be being utilized correctly. You are filling a list and then adding to the list after the fact.

Everything that is added after the query will not be sorted correctly. You'll have to resort your list.

I think it might also benefit you to move your calculation for the delta field into a trigger so that it is populated before this page. This way you can simply use the top 10 query and avoid any additional processing.

**Update**

Based on the comments below, I think your best bet is to:

1. Get rid of the top10 Query all together
2. Build your list based off the data in X[]
3. Sort your data after your list has been built:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm

Comment: Yes, only in the sandbox I am querying all records. I will add the where clause when testing is complete in sandbox. Limiting to 10 records is fine though I am not able to sort list in descending order.

Comment: Read my update. You are pulling data from the database and then adding to it. Everything you add after the query will be out of order.

Comment: This object gets its data from daily Reporting Snapshots and I use X to query identical records between 2 dates [where clause not included here] and then calculate delta between scores. Not sure if using a trigger is a fit for this use case.

Comment: .sort() sorts in ascending order. is there any function available that sorts in descending?

Answer (score 1):

To sort by anything other than the default sort, you just need a wrapper class.

```
class EngagementWrapper implements Comparable {
    Engagement__c record;
    EngagementWrapper(Engagement__c engagement) {
        record = engagement;
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object other) {
        return (Integer)(((EngagementWrapper)other).record.Delta__c-record.Delta__c);
    }
}
```

From there, you can then sort your records as you desire:

```
EngagementWrapper[] temp = new EngagementWrapper[0];
for(Engagement__c record: x) {
    temp.add(new EngagementWrapper(record));
}
temp.sort();
Engagement__c[] top10 = new Engagement__c[0];
for(EngagementWrapper wrapper: temp) {
    top10.add(wrapper.record);
}
return top10;
```

Note that the trick is in compareTo; by subtracting the smaller from the larger, we are reversing the sort order; returning a negative value causes the values in the list to be swapped.

Comment: Thanks. So we are adding x list to temp. Then sorting temp in ASC. Then calling wrapper class to sort in DESC by delta? Also, I keep getting this error:Class must implement the global interface method: Integer compareTo(Object) from Comparable

Comment: Wrapper class is part of the same apex class or do i have to create a separate file for it? Do i have to change my original function to a constructor and add list values to top 10?

Comment: I also need to calculate the delta value before sort. Your code doesn't take that into account.

Comment: @Mike I didn't write out explicitly, but yes, you'll want to calculate the delta first. This code actually expects you to do so. Also, you can put the wrapper in the controller class as an inner class.

Comment: Your implementation [threw them off](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138909/problems-implementing-comparable-class). You're trying to return `Integer` but really it's a `Double`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson doh. It's the simple things I forget to do.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yep. And that's what I get for using my phone to try and edit code.

Comment: I feel your pain. Also I find that casting the parameter instance to a `that` variable makes it easier to type out and read. Comparing `that` and `this` just makes it so much more semantic and easier to wrap heads around that are just trying to pick up the concept in the first place.