# Problems implementing comparable class

Tags: apex, soql, controller, comparable

I am trying to sort list x in descending order by Delta__c. I have been told that I should use a wrapper class and use the implements comparable class. I am getting the error even though Delta__c is an integer field:

> Return value must be of type: Integer for the compareTO class

```
global Class Engagement {

  public List<Engagement__c> top10 {get;set;}   

  public Engagement__c[] getDelta(){

   List<Engagement__c> x = [SELECT Name, ID,Engagement_Score__c,CreatedDate,Account_ID__c,Delta__c,Account_Name__c,Strategic_Account_Tier__c 
                      FROM Engagement__c 
                      WHERE (CreatedDate2EqualsToday_1__c = TRUE OR CreatedDate2MinusYesterday__c = 0 OR CreatedDate2MinusYesterday2__c=2) AND Account_Sales_Team__c = 'US'
                      ORDER BY Account_ID__c,CreatedDate ASC];

    if(!x.isEmpty())
   {
   for(Integer i=1; i<x.size();i++)
    {
        if(x[i].Account_ID__c == x[i-1].Account_ID__c)
        {
             x[i].Delta__c = x[i].Engagement_Score__c-x[i-1].Engagement_Score__c;              
             x.remove(i-1);                  
          i++;            
        }     
        else system.debug('nothing found');
    }
    }
    EngagementWrapper[] temp = new EngagementWrapper[0];
    for(Engagement__c record: x) {
        temp.add(new EngagementWrapper(record));
    }
    temp.sort();
    Engagement__c[] y = new Engagement__c[0];
    for(EngagementWrapper wrapper: temp) {
        y.add(wrapper.record);
    }
    return y;
  }

  global class EngagementWrapper implements Comparable {
    Engagement__c record;
    EngagementWrapper(Engagement__c engagement) {
       record = engagement;
}
global Integer compareTo(Object other) {
    return ((EngagementWrapper)other).record.Delta__c-record.Delta__c;
}
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you need to return an `Integer`. There is no such thing as an `Integer` field in Salesforce. All `Number` fields return a `Double` even if they have 0 trailing digits.

Also, use `public`, not `global`. Never use `global` unless you know for darn sure *why*.

```
public Integer compareTo(Object instance)
{
    MyWrapper that = (MyWrapper)instance;

    // below gives you nulls last
    // reverse the sign to get nulls first
    if (that.record.Delta__c == null) return 1;
    if (this.record.Delta__c == null) return -1;        

    // you can ignore the rounding if you have 0 trailing digits
    return (Integer)(that.record.Delta__c - this.record.Delta__c).round(RoundingMode.UP);
}
```

Note the use of `ROUNDINGMODE.UP` (away from zero). This rounding mechanism ensures you don't accidentally sorting two records in the wrong order because their values are within 1 of each other.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Though now I get the error 'Argument cannot be Null' . I guess values between wrapper and getdelta are not passing.

Comment: @Mike I added some null checking logic to my example.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the explanation. In this, is it also possible to remove nulls from list?

Comment: @Mike You should filter them out in your initial `for` loop. `for (Engagement__c record : x) { if (record.Delta__c != null) { temp.add(new MyWrapper(record)); } }`.

Comment: Oh how did I not see that! :-| Thank you so much!!